# Minimising Runtime Access 2007 backdrop

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Does anyone know if there is a Runtime Access 2007 command line/start up string that will minimise the backdrop window automatically? At the moment, users of my Runtime product have to manually click on the window controls to resize this so that they can see their desktop behind the application.

I don't want the application itself to be minimised, just the main Access window.

Comment: You have to expand on what you mean here. You never could to my knowledge "minimize" the access background. edit: Ah, ok. You don't want Access to start out maximized? Just have users click on the "[]" in the upper right - if the appclation is un-maximized then next time it is launched it will keep that setting (unless you have a applcaiton maximize in your startup routines)

Comment: Thanks Albert. yes, this to have the access background resized to the smallest dimension. Thanks for your suggestions. Initial settings may be the answer, but at them moment the Runtime version always opens with the background maximised regardless of how the Access application is saved beforehand - cheers